# PHP on Windows: Apache or IIS7?

Tags: php, windows, apache, iis-7

Here's the thing:

Due to a new project, I have to learn PHP from scratch. I'm now in windows and I DON'T want to change quickly, so, don't tell me to change.

I need to setup a DreamWeaverCS4/PHP5 develop environment, and, I don't have a clue whether to use Apache or IIS7.
I just need some advice relating to it.

Remarks:

I really don't care about performance(yet), neither portability, and so on. I just need to set it up quickly and easily.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** I'm Using Windows 7 7600 x64

Comment: What version of Windows? That's going to make a difference in which one I'd pick.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up PHP on IIS is pretty simple. Here is what you need now...

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/

Comment: I tried this, with no luck. But I also tried the WebPI (www.microsoft.com/web) and download the installer, checked "PHP for Windows" and everything worked pretty well...
Thanks for the link because it points me where to start

Answer (score 1):

Apache is the best as it's native for the PHP while IIS is foreign. You'll always get help for Apache+PHP here on SO and hardly for PHP+IIS.

Comment: If the OS is Win7 then I agree Apache is the way to go. If it was Windows Server 2008 R2 though, I'd go for IIS. I would disagree that PHP is "foreign" to IIS -- it's just a FastCGI executable which does not care about what webserver executes it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used WAMP yet but I've never had a problem using XAMPP and it's a pretty easy install to get a complete php environment using apache. I wouldn't recommend going the IIS route, its possible but... not worth the effort.

Comment: I use wamp and not xamp and can say the same, they are basically the same thing. Simple to install and provides database too, along with Apache which I would recommend over IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Go and Download WAMP5 Server it is the best and easiest solution for u. By the way it is Apache.

Comment: I don't know, it looks nice but I have a weird felling looking at their screenshots. Looks so Win9x, and i really don't feel confortable with it... Anyway, I'll give it a try.
Thanks

Comment: Yep bro you are right it looks like win9x but i am using it in win7 and did not got any compatibility issue so far.

Comment: I just tried installing WAMP on Windows 7 and I get lots of error dialogs :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Apache+PHP, which brings you mod rewrites, .htaccess and other important features that IIS does not support.

Comment: iis does support URL rewrites and other important features with the web.config file (acts similar to .htaccess).  That being said, I am not a fan of IIS, I am having issues with "Application Pools" running PHP as fastCGI on IIS.

Answer (score -1):

Apache-PHP is the better choice...

Comment: I guess you should state why it's better.